# Unable to print last query in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, activerecord

I am working with codeigniter 4, Right now i am trying to insert data to database,Data is inserting into database but i am unable to print "last query", How can i display "last query" ? I tried with following two ways but not working for me,Here is my model file code

```
public function saveForm($result2){
      $query = $this->db->table("reg_form")->insert($result2);
       echo $this->db->last_query(); // first way
       echo $db->getLastQuery(); // second way
      //return $query;
}
```

Comment: What environment are you executing your code in? Saving queries is disabled in production as it can be expensive to keep queries executed against the database in memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = $this->db->last_query();
print_r($str);
```